# Calling LoadLibrary then FreeLibrary breaks networking

Tags: c#, winapi

Stumbled upon some very weird behaviour today and narrowed it down to this code for reproducing it:

```
TcpListener Listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 8888);
Listener.Start();
TcpClient Client = new TcpClient("localhost", 8888);
IntPtr ModuleHandle = WinApi.LoadLibraryW(@"C:\Windows\system32\ipnathlp.dll"); // <-- Any other DLL here and everything is fine
WinApi.FreeLibrary(ModuleHandle); // <-- Remove this line and everything is fine
byte[] Bytes = new byte[2];
Client.GetStream.Write(Bytes, 0, 2); // <-- Exception thrown here if FreeLibrary is called above:
                                     // "Unable to write data to the transport connection: Either the application
                                     // has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed."
```

and the Win32 APIs are defined like so:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FreeLibrary", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool FreeLibrary([In] IntPtr hLibModule);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibraryW", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryW([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpLibFileName);
```

As you can see from the comments, calling `LoadLibrary` with this specific DLL (`C:\Windows\system32\ipnathlp.dll`) and then freeing it with `FreeLibrary`, makes it so that I can't send data down a network stream without getting this weird exception about WSAStartup.

This DLL is involved with the windows firewall and networking stuff (its description is "Microsoft NAT Helper Components") but regardless of that, shouldn't `LoadLibrary` just be incrementing the reference count by 1 and then `FreeLibrary` decrements it by 1 (so it shouldn't have any effect on the rest of the program if I just load it once and then unload it once) ?

Doing *any* of these things stops this issue from happening and makes everything work fine:

- Changing the target CPU to x86 instead of x64
- Specifying `CharSet=Ansi` in the `LoadLibrary` Dll Import statement (don't feel like I should be doing that though as I'm calling LoadLibraryW for the unicode version and .NET is all unicode, plus I've never had to do that ever before with any other Win32 API call from .NET)
- Removing the call to `FreeLibrary`

This is on a Windows 7 64 bit machine. Haven't had chance to test on anything else yet.

Comment: why do you need to `LoadLibraryW` and then `FreeLibrary` ?

Comment: Looks like `DllMain()` in `ipnathlp.dll` invokes `WSACleanup()` during `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` but does not invoke `WSAStartup()` during `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`. It shouldn't be invoking either, but invoking one and not the other is simply broken; you'll either need to work around it by invoking `WSAStartup()` yourself or avoid loading `ipnathlp.dll`.

Comment: *ipnathlp.dll* isn't part of the public Windows API surface. It's an internal implementation detail of Windows, and your application has no business loading that module.

Comment: @Luke thanks for the perfect explanation. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @vasily.sib obviously that's not all I'm doing in the actual program. This was just a slimmed down example with the bare minimum to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not loading it to call any API from it. I'm just loading it so that I can call `LoadString` to get a string resource from it (because string resources from it are referenced in the services registry key like so: `@%SystemRoot%\system32\ipnathlp.dll,-106` and I need to get the actual string value of that).
I've since replaced this LoadLibrary/LoadString/FreeLibrary method with a single call to `SHLoadIndirectString` and that seems to get the same results but without causing the problem I was experiencing.

Comment: If you call `LoadLibrary`, you **are** loading it with the intention to run code from it. If all you need is access to its resources, use [LoadLibraryEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexw) instead. That doesn't change the situation, though: This module is an implementation detail, and your code has no business using it, even when just reading from its resources. There's an entire [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) dedicated (in part) to explaining how violations like this can turn wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable ah cool I didn't know LoadLibraryEx allowed to load just resources from the DLL. I agree its not ideal to load a resource from an undocumented DLL, but I have no other choice if I want to get the string from a registry value that is a reference to a resource in this undocumented DLL.

Comment: That's a tautology. Who is forcing you to get that string from the registry?